# Let $A= [0,1] - \{1/n │n \in \mathbb{N}\}$. Find $\sup(A)$, $\inf(A)$, $\min(A)$, $\max(A)$.

Tags: supremum-and-infimum

My idea of this question is to claim $\sup(A)$ and $\inf(A)$ exists (and equals a value) and prove by contradiction that $\min(A)$,$\max(A)$ exists afterwards (and equals $\sup(A)$,$\inf(A)$).

The issue that I have is how to interpret set $A$... I'm not sure what $[0,1] - \{1/n │n \in \mathbb{N}\}$ exactly means so I don't know what to claim $\sup(A)$ and $\inf(A)$ to be and prove that claim.

Some guidance would be greatly appreciated, I am not really sure how to go about proving these four conditions in general.

Comment: Your set is the set of points in $[0, 1]$ that are not reciprocals of positive integers.

Comment: stat with sup(A) remember it can be $\geq$ not just $>$

Comment: Hint : $0 \in A$ and $]\frac{1}{2}, 1[ \subset A$.